# More entries in combo box with every call

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a collection `CourtCollection` and a userform `UserFormTest` which includes combobox `CbbCourt`. I want to populate the combobox with data from the collection and then show the userform. Here's the code:

```
Sub RunUserForm()

    'Create the exemplar of the form
    Set Form1 = New UserFormTest

    'Add entries to the combo box from the collection
    For Each Item In CourtCollection
        Form1.CbbCourt.AddItem Item.Item("CourtName")
    Next Item
    Form1.CbbCourt.ListIndex = 1

    Form1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

As a result the combobox contains "item1, item2, item3" on the first userform call, "item1, item2, item3 item1, item2, item3" on the second e.t.c. I understand that it's the exemplar of the userform which persists between calls despite me using `New` keyword in `Set Form1 = New UserFormTest`. I tried to put the code into the event `UserFormTest_Initialize()` but the userform can't "see" my collection. What's wrong and what change should I implement?

Comment: you could create your own method in your userform for populating the combo and an arg for that method would be your collection. Do the set and then `Form1.PopulateCombo(CourtCollection)`

Answer (score 1):

Have a method in the UserForm that accepts a collection and fills the combobox. And then use that method after creating the form, but before showing it. This will give you better control and maintainability of your code.

And **always** use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module. Always.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RunUserForm(courtCollection as Collection) ' <-- always reduce the use of globals!
Dim Form1 as UserFormTest
    Set Form1 = New UserFormTest
    Form1.UpdateMyBox(courtCollection)
    ' … could also have other initialitising actions?
    Form1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

In the Form code itself (not tested):

```
Option Explicit
Sub UpDateMyBox(values as Collection) ' Assumes standard Collection - modify for a custom Collection.
Dim collectionItem as Variant 'Strongly type this depending on what is expected in the Collection.

    Me.CbbCourt.Clear
    For Each collectionItem In values
        Me.CbbCourt.AddItem collectionItem ' I am assuming an ordinary Collection here
    Next collectionItem 
    Me.CbbCourt.ListIndex = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: But what if I need my combobox  entries to refer back the entries of the collection? I think it's better to put 95% of all the code into the Userform itself then, isn't it?

Comment: Btw, calling this sub from the main module like `Form1.UpdateMyBox(courtCollection)` doesnt solve the problem of items duplicating every time I call the userform.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov: Comboboxes don't do anything other than list items. You missed the `Clear` command (again, not tested but the intent is to clear the box before you populate it whenever you re-use it). And you did not provide enough information in the OP to suggest you were doing anything with the ComboBox, so this answer answers the direct question as posed.